# Is it possible to leave the Solar System by repeatedly using gravity assists from the Earth?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, gravity-assist

If a spacecraft was accelerated to just above Earth's escape velocity, it would begin orbiting the sun with an orbit very similar to Earth's. Could the spacecraft then repeatedly perform a gravity assist with the Earth to increase it's apogee over and over until it left the Solar System, while only using a nominal amount of delta-v to perform deep-space maneuvers to fine-tune encounters with the Earth?

Comment: several millennia per slingshot, once it passes beyond Sedna orbit, aside?

Comment: I might have to model this in KSP...

Comment: Oh, and is a Jupiter flyby after initial Earth flybys okay?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto for this question I want to know if leaving the Solar System is possible using only Earth flybys.

Comment: I like this question - it reminds me a little bit of [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) - they look for fewest characters, here we can look for fewest flybys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Juno did something similar to this, it went on an initial 2 year orbit, with a flyby of Earth 2 years after launch, after which time it went on to Jupiter, to orbit it.

I've been playing a bit with [NASA's Trajectory Browser](http://trajbrowser.arc.nasa.gov/traj_browser.php?maxMag=25&maxOCC=4&chk_target_list=on&target_list=Jupiter&mission_class=oneway&mission_type=rendezvous&LD1=2016&LD2=2040&maxDT=20&DTunit=yrs&maxDV=7.0&min=DV&wdw_width=365&submit=Search#a_load_results), and found this possibility:

- Launch March 2016- 4.33 km/s beyond Earth Escape
- Deep space maneuver 1 year later
- Slight powered flyby of Earth 10 months later
- Pick the correct course to flyby Jupiter, such that the flight will lead to interstellar space

Total ~ 5 km/s delta v.

[image]

If you want to do a purely Earth based escape, it is also possible, the trick is to periodically return to Earth. So the first return time would be in 2 years, the next might be in 4, and so on until you have left the Solar System. It might take a while, but it could be done.